# Sort Spreadsheet by Each Column, Then Paste into New File

Tags: excel, sorting, copy

Is it possible for Excel 2000 to take a spreadsheet and sort by each column, and after each sort to copy the rows that contain data in the sorted column to a new file?

I have a column of email addresses, and next to it are 137 columns that are mailing lists that the addresses might be associated with. So if the address is associated with a particular list, it will have an x under that list. However, now I need to isolate all the different lists into separate files. I can do it manually, but I was hoping there could be some script that I can tweak to do the job.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

I don't think you can do this in two separate files. Could you paste the sheets with x's over to the email file?

There are several ways to sort the email addresses by your different groupings. While manually sorting may be your best bet, Microsoft has an interesting page on [how to use mail merge to send personalized email messages to your email list](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/use-mail-merge-to-send-personalized-e-mail-messages-to-your-e-mail-address-list-HA010109162.aspx).

You could combine the filtered email list with your next step: actually mailing to the list.

Comment: Thanks, rajah9. There is actually no emailing. It's only sorting and copying of Excel data into new spreadsheets. I'm just going to do it manually.